# Can pandas dataframe have dtype of list?

Tags: python, string, list, pandas, list-comprehension

I'm new to Pandas, I process a dataset, where one of the columns is string with pipe (`|`) separated values. Now I have a task to remove any text in this |-separated field that's not fulfilling certain criteria.

My naive approach is to iterate the dataframe row by row and explode the field into list and validate this way. Then write the modified row back to the original dataframe. See this metasample:

```
for index, row in dataframe.iterrows():
    fixed = [x[:29] for x in row['field'].split('|')]
    dataframe.loc[index, 'field'] = "|".join(fixed)
```

Is there a better, and more importantly faster way to do this?

Comment: On first blush this just seems to me like a misuse of the data structure. Why have a column that is a list of fields separated by a delimiter? What are the other columns?

Comment: Could you provide any example of that column or dataframe?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga well, that's how the data comes to me in the CSV. There are other columns too, but this is the only one that has list-like structure. The point is that in the original data that comes to me, sometimes one of those values is wrong...and I need to filter it off before I work further with the dataset

Comment: @AntonProtopopov that's kind of trivial...take this sample:
`pandas.DataFrame({'ID' : [1,2,3,4],'FIELD' : ['aa|abc','bc|bb','c','d']})`
the requirement is that a value in FIELD is no longer than 2 characters...so abc in ID 1 has to be filtered out

Comment: @MichalHolub it's better to attach that example to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can use:

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'field':['aasd|bbuu|cccc|ddde|e','ffff|gggg|hhhh|i|j','cccc|u|k'],
                          'G':[4,5,6]})

print (dataframe)
   G                  field
0  4  aasd|bbuu|cccc|ddde|e
1  5     ffff|gggg|hhhh|i|j
2  6               cccc|u|k


print (dataframe.field.str.split('|', expand=True)
                          .stack()
                          .str[:2] #change to 29
                          .groupby(level=0)
                          .apply('|'.join))

0    aa|bb|cc|dd|e
1     ff|gg|hh|i|j
2           cc|u|k
dtype: object
```

Another solution via list comprehension:

```
dataframe['new'] = pd.Series([[x[:2] for x in y] for y in dataframe.field.str.split('|')], 
                             index=dataframe.index)
                     .apply('|'.join)
print (dataframe)
   G                  field            new
0  4  aasd|bbuu|cccc|ddde|e  aa|bb|cc|dd|e
1  5     ffff|gggg|hhhh|i|j   ff|gg|hh|i|j
2  6               cccc|u|k         cc|u|k
```

---

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'field':['aasd|bbuu|cc|ddde|e','ffff|gggg|hhhh|i|j','cccc|u|k'],
                   'G':[4,5,6]})

print (dataframe)
   G                field
0  4  aasd|bbuu|cc|ddde|e
1  5   ffff|gggg|hhhh|i|j
2  6             cccc|u|k
```

If need filter all values with values longer as `2`:

```
s = dataframe.field.str.split('|', expand=True).stack()
print (s)
0  0    aasd
   1    bbuu
   2      cc
   3    ddde
   4       e
1  0    ffff
   1    gggg
   2    hhhh
   3       i
   4       j
2  0    cccc
   1       u
   2       k
dtype: object

dataframe['new'] = s[s.str.len() < 3].groupby(level=0).apply('|'.join)
print (dataframe)

   G                field   new
0  4  aasd|bbuu|cc|ddde|e  cc|e
1  5   ffff|gggg|hhhh|i|j   i|j
2  6             cccc|u|k   u|k
```

Another solution:

```
dataframe['new'] = pd.Series([[x for x in y if len(x) < 3] for y in dataframe.field.str.split('|')], 
                              index=dataframe.index)
                     .apply('|'.join)
print (dataframe)
   G                field   new
0  4  aasd|bbuu|cc|ddde|e  cc|e
1  5   ffff|gggg|hhhh|i|j   i|j
2  6             cccc|u|k   u|k
```